# GRUB, device not found, root delay problem

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

My Kali suddenly froze, when I reset my computer, I started getting GRUB's device not found error. After disconnecting and reconnecting my HDDs many times, I finally got it to a state where GRUB's device not found error is only momentarily shown then boot menu with OS list comes up but when I select Kali, I get the error shown in the image.

[image]

But when I select Win 7 which is on the same HDD, it loads without problems. This is only happening with Kali

I have some important files on my Kali desktop, is there a way to repair this problem. Or is there way to get to those files? Like from Live Kali or Win 7. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Your root device looks like missing. Start with another livecd, and do `grub-mkconfig` with `chroot` (should be google-able).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened to your OS, but I can surely tell you that SysRescueCd  liveCD will get your files back. as long your drives are not badly damaged you can get your files back 100%. Get it here http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

Answer (score -1):

It's happen when you restart your system unexpected when the root device mounted and work .

1. The strongest theory is that you miss your root drive and system files

> Solution : just if you have backup file from your root partition you can restore your system

2. but sometime the problem is your Partition on hard driver :

> Solution: i recommend to use this tools [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) , it's will
>   repair your hdd bad sectors and even with this tools you can recovery
>   your lost files .

if you wanna restore your files , boot a linux distributions (alike kali ) in live mode and mount your partition with :

```
mkdir /mnt/kali    
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda? /mnt/kali
```

the /dev/sda? is different in each hdd and depend on type of hdd and partition , example /dev/sda2
you also can see your partitions with **lsblk** command

and check your kali root files is there or you need to recovery them